# Android webview: How to get webview to load my website

Tags: android, web, webview

So I am currently trying to learn the android webview but have run into some issues. I got it to load youtube.com perfectly but when I try my website it will not work; I just get a blank white screen. Why is that? My website does not have https and this is my code inside the activity's .java class:

```
    web = new WebView(this);
    web.loadUrl("nickhulsey.com");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    setContentView(web);
```

Is it some sort of security issue or is my website not built properly for the webview to work?

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute URL:

```
web.loadUrl("http://nickhulsey.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help and it is a minimal better practice to implement webview...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

  private WebView wv1;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
     wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());

     String url = "http://nickhulsey.com/";

        wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv1.loadUrl(url);
     }
  });
  }

  private class MyClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
   }
```